# How should you prove a rational function increases?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Suppose that $f(0) = 0$ and that $f'$ is increasing. Prove that the function
>       $g(x) = f(x)/x$ is increasing on $(0,\infty)$. *hint: Use the mean value theorem*
>       on $f(x)$ on the right interval.

I tried very hard to do this problem but I failed repeatedly. One of the issues is the interval being to infinity?

$$f''(x) > 0$$

Obviously,

$$g'(x) = \frac{xf'(x) - f(x)}{x^2} > 0$$

Is the objective to be proven;

$$xf'(x) - f(x) > 0$$

Meaning,

$$f'(x) > g(x)$$ For $x \in (0, \infty)$

I will try proof by contradiction.

Suppose $f'(x) < g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x}$ $\forall x$

By the mean value theorem,

$$f'(x_1) = \frac{f(x_1) - f(0)}{x - 0} = g(x_1)$$ for two points, $x = x_1$ and $x = 0$.

Which is a contradiction to $f'(x) < g(x)$.

Now, suppose $f'(x) = g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x}$.

Then by the hypothesis, $f'(x)$ is increasing, which would mean $g'(x) > 0$.

Proof complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noted, it suffices to show that $f'(x) > g(x)$ for all $x$. However, in your proof by contradiction, you assumed $f'(x) < g(x)$ for all $x$, which is not the negation of the statement $$f'(x) > g(x)\quad \text{for all $x$}.$$

What you should suppose in your proof by contradiction is that $f'(x) \le g(x)$ for some $x$.

I'll show you a direct way to prove $f'(x) > g(x)$ for all $x$ (or $xf'(x) > f(x)$ for all $x$). By the mean value theorem, for each $x > 0$, $f(x) - f(0) = f'(c_x)x$ for some $c_x\in (0,x)$. Since $f(0) = 0$ and $f'$ is increasing, $f(x) = f'(c_x)x < f'(x)x$ for all $x$.

Comment: I did do that though. My last few lines I say suppose $f'(x)=g(x)$

Comment: Also in your proof what about points, $x< C_x$ ??

Comment: @Ama no, it's $c_x \in (0,x)$, or $0 < c_x < x$. Also, even though you supposed in the end that $f'(x) = g(x)$, in the beginning of the argument, you assumed $f'(x) < g(x)$ for all $x$. The main issue is the term "for all $x$". It should be replaced by "for some $x$".

Comment: if I say for some $x$ then how does it prove the criteria for all x given in the problem?

Comment: You were trying to contradict the statement $f'(x) > g(x)$ for all $x$. The negation of the statement is $f'(x) \le g(x)$ for some $x$. By assuming the negation and the hypothesis, arriving at a contradiction then proves the result.

Comment: How do you find negations in general?

Comment: I can't give a full summary here, but for this problem, the following will be useful. The negation of "for every" is "for some" and the negation of "$a < b$" is "$a \ge b$". Also, the negation of the statement "$P$ and $Q$" is "not $P$ and not $Q$".

Comment: So how should I get a contradiction for $f'(x) = g(x)$?

Comment: @Ama by the MVT, $f(x) = f'(c_x)x < f'(x)x$, where $0 < c_x < x$. So $g(x) < f'(x)$, a contradiction.